build boost shared library for android on macos
while the static libs were built successfully, i'd like to build the shared libs also.
the key error is the linker options:

clang60++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-single_module' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang60++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dynamiclib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang60++: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-install_name @rpath/libboost_thread.so.1.78.0' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
/Users/wellbye/repo/m/hm/h5ui@dev/.build/ndk_toolchain/arm64/bin/../sysroot/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o: In function _start_main': crtbegin.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to main'
crtbegin.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `main'

i think it's from the action in /tools/build/src/tools/clang-darwin.jam due to match the clang and darwin:
actions link.dll bind LIBRARIES
{
    "$(CONFIG_COMMAND)" $(USER_OPTIONS) -L"$(LINKPATH)" -o "$(<)" -single_module -dynamiclib -install_name "@rpath/$(<[1]:D=)" "$(>)"  "$(LIBRARIES)" $(START-GROUP) $(FINDLIBS-ST-PFX) -l$(FINDLIBS-ST) $(FINDLIBS-SA-PFX) -l$(FINDLIBS-SA) $(END-GROUP) $(OPTIONS)
}

but it should only be applied to darwin native build, not the ndk clang when doing cross compiling, which insteadly accepts '-shared' for this purpose.
if i just modify the builtin clang-darwin.jam file and change the options, the build will go well. but i'd like to know if there's a more none-intrusive method to overwrite this? for example setting it in the user-config.jam, but no success on tries.

What commands are you using to build?
